How to find who is using the memory
I am trying to find out what is using my memory, when running free -m I get info that only 1GB is free as aswell as available. However, running the top shows process only using 0.7% memory so I am not sure where to look at.
The only potentional I found is when using ipcs and taking look at the active shared memory segments.
Here is the output of the commands:
[root@test ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         100408       93195        1147        4059        6064        1109
Swap:         16383           0       16383


top - 01:37:10 up 20 days, 11:11,  1 user,  load average: 1.99, 2.43, 2.09
Tasks: 821 total,   4 running, 718 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 26.8 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 70.4 id,  0.3 wa,  0.6 hi,  0.3 si,  0.1 st
GiB Mem :     98.1 total,      1.2 free,     90.8 used,      6.1 buff/cache
GiB Swap:     16.0 total,     16.0 free,      0.0 used.      1.4 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5567 root      20   0 2420880 755000   7532 S   0.3  0.7 138:59.28 java
61283 oracle    20   0   11.0g 661820 355908 S   0.3  0.6  22:34.72 ora_m003_lmxlb1
 3203 root      20   0 3708312 516148 116856 S   0.3  0.5  16:56.21 cvd
17260 oracle    20   0   11.1g 437816  77184 S   0.3  0.4  22:39.85 ora_m003_lmxlb1
 8413 oracle    20   0 4688756 417056  35188 S   0.7  0.4 226:19.91 java
65826 oracle    20   0   11.0g 401372  92988 S   0.0  0.4   0:02.63 ora_j003_lmxlb1
69002 oracle    20   0   11.1g 399332  86052 S   0.0  0.4   0:03.41 ora_j002_lmxlb1
51455 oracle    20   0   11.0g 399120  90912 S   0.0  0.4   0:03.71 ora_j001_lmxlb1
79327 oracle    20   0   11.1g 397784  83320 S   0.3  0.4  22:57.12 ora_m004_lmxlb1
17163 oracle    20   0   11.0g 397420  92532 S   0.0  0.4  22:26.38 ora_m002_lmxlb1
93154 oracle    20   0   11.0g 389156  86464 S   0.0  0.4   7:12.23 ora_m001_lmxlb1
22405 oracle    20   0   11.0g 349296  80512 S   0.0  0.3   9:56.93 ora_m000_lmxlb1
61251 oracle    20   0   11.0g 347620  92740 S   0.0  0.3  22:24.97 ora_m002_lmxlb1
61249 oracle    20   0   11.0g 316504  89020 S   0.0  0.3  22:17.43 ora_m001_lmxlb1
11754 oracle    20   0   10.7g 311644  66756 S   0.7  0.3  61:25.02 ora_ppa7_lmxlb1
77645 oracle    20   0 3803892 290100  20516 S   0.3  0.3   1:09.30 java
 3234 root      20   0 2977240 265384      0 S   0.0  0.3   6:43.82 CvMountd
 5752 oracle    rt   0 2745664 256364 114388 S   0.7  0.2 205:16.78 ocssd.bin


[root@test ~]# ipcs -m | awk 'NR==1; NR > 1 { printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, ($5/1024/1024)" MB" }'

------     Shared     Memory     Segments   --------                         0 MB
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status     0 MB
0xfa002e17 0          root       660        59828264   1                     57.0567 MB
0xfa002e19 32769      root       660        59828264   1                     57.0567 MB
0x3ea248d0 720898     oracle     600        28672      48                    0.0273438 MB
0x00000000 786435     oracle     640        67108864   57                    64 MB
0x00000000 819204     oracle     640        10670309376 57                    10176 MB
0xdc9e3d00 851973     oracle     640        2097152    57                    2 MB
0x00000000 884742     oracle     600        4194304    112                   4 MB
0x00000000 917511     oracle     600        10670309376 112                   10176 MB
0x00000000 950280     oracle     600        65011712   112                   62 MB
0xcd035180 983049     oracle     600        2097152    112                   2 MB
0x00000000 1015818    oracle     600        14680064   114                   14 MB
0x00000000 1048587    oracle     600        16072572928 114                   15328 MB
0x00000000 1081356    oracle     600        20971520   114                   20 MB
0x233b805c 1114125    oracle     600        2097152    114                   2 MB
0x00000000 26837006   oracle     600        14680064   151                   14 MB
0x00000000 26869775   oracle     600        10468982784 151                   9984 MB
0x00000000 26902544   oracle     600        20971520   151                   20 MB
0x40c4f358 26935313   oracle     600        2097152    151                   2 MB
0x00000000 1277970    oracle     600        14680064   129                   14 MB
0x00000000 1310739    oracle     600        10468982784 129                   9984 MB
0x00000000 1343508    oracle     600        20971520   129                   20 MB
0x8d83344c 1376277    oracle     600        2097152    129                   2 MB
                                                                             0 MB


Oracle user in shared memory segments use >45GB.

@RomeoNinov this is means that from 93GB used more then > 45GB are used by oracle shared memory segments?

By my understanding - yes, sum the column 5 (or 7) of ipcs result

When running top, press the 'M' keystroke (uppercase m or Shift-m) and the list of processes will be sorted by their memory consumption from largest to smallest.  This can be a fairly fast way to find the biggest consumers of memory.

@SottoVoce the output looks like it is already sorted by memory.

The output is already sorted by memory and the unit has been set to MB to read it out easier, right now the only explanation is like @RomeoNinov mentioned, if I find something better, I will update you guys, thanks.

@paganini, for reference you can check SGA and SGA_MAX_SIZE parameters of Oracle database.

The issue has been found, the system was stable even with the "low" memory. So, the HugePages were allocated, which is good thing, however the total number was too big (80GB).
[root@test ~]# grep Huge /proc/meminfo
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:   40000
HugePages_Free:    15672
HugePages_Rsvd:     3617
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

So after, setting the kernel parameter vm.nr_hugepages = 30000, we have visibly more free memory.
[root@test ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         100408       70007       21362        3875        9037       24336
Swap:         16383           0       16383


-You can know how the processes are running using the command ps -aux that just gives you the list of the processes and you can see how they are running and the memory and everything else used, ok!

This wouldn’t help here, because the problem was related to huge page allocations, OK!
